# Cordova Plugin installation, ios.json syntax not correct

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins

My latest problem with cordova 3.4.0 is that ios.json is not updated with the correct syntax. When I install barcodescanner with plugman I'd expect the corresponding ios.json entry to be formatted as such:

```
{"xml": "<feature name=\"BarcodeScanner\"><param name=\"ios-package\" value=\"CDVBarcodeScanner\" /></feature>", "count": 1}
```

Instead, this is what I get:

```
"config.xml": {
        "/*": {
            "<feature name=\"BarcodeScanner\"><param name=\"ios-package\" value=\"CDVBarcodeScanner\" /></feature>": 1
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I manually convert all entries for the generated config.xml as above, including those for the iOS Framework dependencies, the plugin works. e.g. (and other similar framework entries for dependencies)

```
 "AudioToolbox.framework": {
            "false": 1
        }
```

convert to:

```
 "AudioToolbox.framework": [
                    {
                        "xml": "true",
                        "count": 1
                    }
                ],
```

Plus the config.xml as above from:

```
    "config.xml": {
        "/*": {
            "<feature name=\"BarcodeScanner\"><param name=\"ios-package\" value=\"CDVBarcodeScanner\" /></feature>": 1
        }
    }
```

to:

```
 {"xml": "<feature name=\"BarcodeScanner\"><param name=\"ios-package\" value=\"CDVBarcodeScanner\" /></feature>", "count": 1}
```

Might be of some help to others.